# How to squash commits after the pull request has been opened?

Tags: git

I've looked at all the possible answers on SO and also have read blogs but I think I've messed up pretty bad.

I tried -

`git rebase -i upstream/master`

and then changing `pick` to `squash` after the first line, but I was getting merge conflicts again and again. So finally I read an answer on SO which recommended this -

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Missing parameter: number of commits to squash."
    exit 1
fi

echo "Squashing $1 commits..."
git reset --soft HEAD~$1
git log --format=%B%n --reverse "HEAD@{1}" -n $1 > _msg.txt
git commit -t _msg.txt
rm _msg.txt
echo "Done!"
```

So I tried `git-squash 6` and I think this messed it up harder. If you need any more information just ask.

Heres the PR -

https://github.com/mushorg/glutton/pull/62

[image]

Comment: Github has sqashing option

Comment: @TusharKotlapure That option is only for the owners of the repository I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I start with the upstream repository:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/mushorg/glutton
$ cd glutton
```

And just to make my remote names look like yours:

```
$ git remote rename origin upstream
```

Then I fetch your PR:

```
$ git fetch upstream pull/62/head
$ git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

You would obviously not need this step, since you already have your changes locally.

Just to confirm I'm looking at the same thing you are, I see the following changes:

```
$ git log --oneline master..
cdbca37 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/HashCode55/glutton
b37aafd SMTP responses fixed and random wait time added
f25198e supports random wait time for response
4cfcc1d random removed
f2bfed7 refactor
da3dbdb refactor
3bfb62c removed rand function
1bb8a43 SMTP responses fixed
088f6df merged
a383e09 Revert "Revert "removed""
f1bb1c2 Revert "removed"
97bac3f removed
97a0408 Changes
```

A few things jump out there:

- You will probably find things more manageable if you work on a feature branch rather than your own `master` branch.  That is, start with `git checkout -b my-spiffy-feature` before you start making any changes.  If you will be regularly contributing upstream, your life is easiest if your `master` branch always reflects the state of the upstream `master` branch at some point in time, because this permits you to update your local master branch with a simple `git pull upstream master`.
- Avoiding merging code into your feature branches.  Regularly rebase on `upstream/master` if you need to incorporate upstream changes.
- Avoid generating revert commits in your feature branch.  Just use `git reset`.

If you were to follow the above steps you would avoid all the conflicts and complication that brought you to this point.

The easiest way to squash all of these changes is probably start by resetting your current branch back to the upstream `master` branch:

```
$ git reset upstream/master
```

This will reset the repository, but *not* your working directory, to the state of the `upstream/master` branch.  Since it doesn't modify the state of your working directory, this means that all your changes are preserved, but not the commit history.  At this point, we see:

```
$ git status
[...]
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/server.go
    modified:   smtp.go

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Now we can create a new commit:

```
$ git add -u
$ git commit
```

Now you have a single commit on top of the upstream `master` branch.  You would then force push this to your own `master` branch, which would update the PR.

(NB: if you're worried about screwing something up or losing your changes or anything like that, either work on a new branch, or just make a local copy of your working directory and work on that instead.)

Comment: This helped a lot, really. But I'm still missing something. In my git status it says - `Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 13 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)` along with your output.

Comment: I believe that in your local repository, `origin` refers to *your* github repository (`HashCode55/glutton`), and you have in fact just truncated your history with respect to that repo (because of the `git reset`), so that's okay.  You should be 1 head of `upstream/master`, and running `git log` should confirm that you have one commit, with your changes, on top of the current `upstream/master` branch.

Comment: I've updated the question with a screenshot of the error I'm talking about.

Comment: That's not an error, that's the expected state, as I indicated in my last comment.

Comment: But now when I'm trying to push to `origin/master` its saying "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
'git pull ...') before pushing again.
See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.".

Comment: The point is if I do git pull I'll be again making the commits which I want to squash. How can I ignore those 13 commits at `origin/master`?

Comment: Don't `git pull`.  You don't want those commits; why would you try to bring them back?  You want to *force push* (`git push -f`) to update *your* github repository. You want to *replace* the state of the remote repo with the state of your local repository.

Comment: Yeah finally did that, really thanks a lot (I know you cannot say it here but yeah). Also can you remove that "This PR is a step towards fixing #53 and #25" (by removing your fork) because it's getting referenced on the main issue?